# Not able to build .war with SpringBootServletInitializer (using Gradle build)

Tags: spring-boot

Am getting *filename.java:6: error: package org.springframework.boot.context.web does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;*

Source code :--

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

build.gradle :--

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

war {
baseName = 'temp'
version =  '0.0.2'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
compile("com.h2database:h2")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile("junit:junit")
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

Any pointers would be very helpful. 
Is there a missing starter dependency...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot 2.0 where `SpringBootServletInitializer` is in the `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support` package.

Comment: Thanks Andy. The build went through. Generated .war file is executing well at localhost:8080, But cf push taskmgr -p build\libs\temp.War is still unsuccessful. [cf push taskmgr -p build\libs\temp.Jar works well, when deployed to cfapps.io.] cf logs indicate something like ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer.

Comment: That’s really a separate problem that would be better asked as a separate question. That said, I suspect you nee to use a different version of the Java buildpack.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Andy. I have also posted a separate question.